# How do you calculate the probability of getting 1 new customer out of X using Excel?

Tags: excel

How do you calculate the probability of getting 1 new customer out of X.  I am expecting to come up with 2,3,4...10.  I have tried using the probability function, but it doesn't seem to like what I am using for parameters.

=BINOM.DIST(1,500,1/500,TRUE)

Comment: Maybe the question is how do I calculate the odds of converting 1 customer out of 500, 2 customer out of 500, 3 customer out of 500...

Comment: Excel has to be told the probability of a success in one trial. Imagine 2 sales people: 1 has a probability of .4 /trial, and 2 has a probability of .15 /trial. 1 has been selling this product for 10 years, and 2 has only been on the job for 6 mos. Excel can say for each salesperson, the probability of n successes in N trials is going to be X. But it will be different for each one, because they don't both sell the same amount of product. When you make a call, what are the chances you will make the sale? Look at your historical conversion and see if you can figure that out.

Comment: What would 2 look like?  =BINOM.DIST(1,500,2/500,TRUE)?  because the drop off doesn't feel right at 67.67.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in what sense this "doesn't work". Excel is returning exactly what you asked for: the cumulative probability of 1 success out of 500 trials where the probability of success is 1/500 in each independent trial.

Instead of looking at the cumulative distribution, though, consider each possible number of successes separately:

[image]

If the probability of getting a customer is 1/500, then if you ask 500 people, there is a 36.8% chance that you will get zero customers. There is also a 36.8% chance that you'll get one new customer, for a cumulative probability of 73.6%. There is a 99.6% chance that you will get 4 or fewer new customers from 500 tries.

To be clear, the formula for the "Prob" column is

```
=BINOM.DIST(cell_with_success_number,500,1/500,0)
```

Comment: `If the probability of getting a customer is 1/500`. Unless I'm mistaken, I think this is the very probability value that Steve is hoping Excel will provide him with. This is why the question cannot be answered.

Comment: My error was that if my successes was 2 I was using 2/500 and if it was 3 I used 3/500.  I think I am close to what I am looking for.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

> BINOM.DIST(number_s,trials,probability_s,cumulative)
>
> - Number_s         The number of successes in trials.
> - Trials           The number of independent trials.
> - Probability_s        The probability of success on each trial.
> - Cumulative      A logical value that determines the form of the function. If cumulative is TRUE, then BINOM.DIST returns the
>     cumulative distribution function, which is the probability that there
>     are at most number_s successes; if FALSE, it returns the probability
>     mass function, which is the probability that there are number_s
>     successes.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/binom-dist-function-HP010335671.aspx

It returns a probability (0< X<1), so a value between 0 and 1. Note that "Probability of success in each trial" is asking what the chances are of getting a new customer EACH time you call (one trial). By entering 1/500, it appears you are assuming a probability of 0.002 for each trial. The resulting answer of 0.736 indicates you have a 73.6% chance of getting 1 new client for each 500 calls, or "trials".

Do you have a number you can enter based on your past experience calling leads?

Comment: No, think of this more as I have 500 post cards going out how many will generate a call?1...10+

Comment: Steve, this isn't a question Excel can answer without more information. It doesn't know how many people respond to postcards, decide to buy after a phone call, etc. You are looking for an answer to something that every salesperson would kill to know. You can only use this function if you know the probability of a success in one trial. Then, excel can take that data and calculate k successes in n  trials if it follows the binomial distribution.

Comment: No, there is a 73.6% chance of getting zero or one new customers. See my answer.

Comment: I guess I am trying to forecast the amounts before I get the actuals.